# How to authenticate against openml.org

Tags: python, authentication, openml

I'm trying to run an [openml](https://openml.org) benchmark, and it
rightfully asks for an API key. The issue is I cannot find
in the API docs how to provide that key.

The [user guide](https://docs.openml.org/Python-start/) says:

```py
import openml
from sklearn import impute, tree, pipeline

# Define a scikit-learn classifier or pipeline
clf = pipeline.Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('imputer', impute.SimpleImputer()),
        ('estimator', tree.DecisionTreeClassifier())
    ]
)
# Download the OpenML task for the german credit card dataset with 10-fold
# cross-validation.
task = openml.tasks.get_task(31)
# Run the scikit-learn model on the task.
run = openml.runs.run_model_on_task(clf, task)
# Publish the experiment on OpenML (optional, requires an API key.
# You can get your own API key by signing up to OpenML.org)
run.publish()
print(f'View the run online: {openml.config.server}/run/{run.run_id}')
```

But it doesn't specify how I'm supposed to provide that key.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the library expects the key to be in the `~/.openml/config` file, as:

```
apikey=your_secret_key
```

Answer (score 0):

This explains how to configure OpenML:
https://openml.github.io/openml-python/master/examples/20_basic/introduction_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-examples-20-basic-introduction-tutorial-py

It's indeed best to store your key in a local file. You can also set it programmatically for quick testing (but never share your API key!):

```
openml.config.apikey = 'YOURKEY'
```